# Why do I get this discrepancy when doing meta-programming with Ruby on Rails ActiveSupport Time Extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I was playing around with ActiveSupport Time Core Extensions (rails 4.1.2).
And here is a problem which I came across.

Why do I get this discrepancy?

```
2.0.0-p451 :011 >   Time.zone.now
=> Wed, 23 Jul 2014 16:38:21 EDT -04:00 

2.0.0-p451 :012 > 4.months.ago
=> Sun, 23 Mar 2014 16:38:25 EDT -04:00 

2.0.0-p451 :013 > 4.send(:months).send(:ago)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #ago or #until on a number (e.g. 5.ago) is deprecated and  
will be removed in the future, use 5.seconds.ago instead. (called from irb_binding at 
(irb):13)
=> Tue, 25 Mar 2014 16:38:35 EDT -04:00
```

I see a problem on the last statement: 2 days later to what `4.months.ago` returns. Also, I get a warning, whereas when calling `4.months.ago` I do not get one.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned by `4.months` is an `ActiveSupport::Duration`, which inherits from `ActiveSupport::ProxyObject` → [`BasicObject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/BasicObject.html). `BasicObject` doesn't behave like other objects, and in this particular case it's relevant that `BasicObject` doesn't have a `send` method:

```
[7] pry(main)> BasicObject.new.send
NoMethodError: undefined method `send' for #<BasicObject:0x007f9e23997910>
```

In `ActiveSupport::Duration`, [there's an implementation for `method_missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.2/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L114) which passes unknown methods through to the underlying numeric object.

So, when you call `4.send(:months).send(:ago)`, you are sending the `ago` method call to the underlying `Fixnum` rather than the `ActiveSupport::Duration` object.

This breaks the `months` calculation, because `4.months` becomes 120 days when converted to a number:

```
[9] pry(main)> 4.months.to_i
=> 10368000
[10] pry(main)> 120.days.to_i
=> 10368000
```

**Edit:** You can work around this using the `__send__` method, but it's not really the preferred way to do things:

```
[15] pry(main)> 4.months.__send__(:ago)
=> Sun, 23 Mar 2014 21:14:20 UTC +00:00
[16] pry(main)> 4.months.ago
=> Sun, 23 Mar 2014 21:14:27 UTC +00:00
```